# MJML 4 button shadow

Tags: newsletter, mjml

How can I add css attributes box-shadow to standard "mj-button" components?

I'm using the node version 4.5

This is the code of my button:

```
<mj-button css-class="box-shadow" align="left" background-color="#95C11F" href="#">Button 1</mj-button>
```

I have tried with the css-class having this code:

```
<mj-style>
    .box-shadow > table td {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); 
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    }
</mj-style>
```

But no shadow is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

See https://mjml.io/try-it-live/HySjzKsDv

That's your MJML code, except that I substituted "red" for the rgba() calls. I see a shadow I didn't see before the change.

I can't find it in the MJML documentation that MJML doesn't support rgba(), but it's a "modern" enough addition to HTML that I wouldn't depend on it being in all the email clients MJML authors target. Some are pretty basic.

All the color examples in the MJML documentation I can remember use hex notation ("#F45E43") or named colors.

Good luck.